# leaflet L.control.attribution

Tags: javascript, leaflet, css3pie

Thank you for offering your help here. I have built a MapBox application. I wanted to add a copyright prior to MapBox's copyright logo. I used the L.control.attribution as:

```
varName = L.control.attribution({prefix: 'some text'}).addTo(map);
```

I used FireFox inspector and found that `some text` is a child of ->  a div `class="leaflet-control-attribution leaflet-control"` from leaflet.css.

I have my own custom.css file and I tried to use it to override the class leaflet-control-attribution in leaflet.css but it is not working. Is this something from MapBox.css to prevents overriding or from leaflet? Is there a solution to fix this? I just wanted to change the background of the parent div of the `L.control.attribution` DOM object.

Thanks in advance.

Ahmad

Comment: Provide please your css code with which you have tried to override the class.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it by this way

```
var leafletMap = L.map('map').setView([23.709921, 90.407143], 7);

 leafletMap.attributionControl.addAttribution('Licensed by &copy; <a href="some_link", class="your_class">Habijabi</a>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an html text in place of "sometext".

```
varName = L.control.attribution({prefix: '<span class="AttributionClass">some text</span>'}).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score -1):

*leaflet-control-attribution* is probably getting over-ridden. try adding '*!important*' to the css attribute.